# GlobalSize function used on Clipboard Data cause error

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, desktop-application, access-violation

The first thing I want to say is my English is pretty bad so if my description become a chunk of nonsense text please comment so I can try to clarify my question.

**The situation**

I'm trying to access clipboard and store all of it's data from all formats possible. I listen to [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649021(v=vs.85).aspx) message then loop through all the format available, get the data for each of the format, get the size then allocate a new memory for them. My googling tell me to use the [`GlobalSize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366593(v=vs.85).aspx) function to do that. There the problem arise.

**The environment**

I am developing a Win32 desktop application using C++ on Visual C++ 2017 version 4.7.02556. I am using Windows 10 64 bits if that matter.

**Reproducing the error**

Here is my function used to process Windows messages, I remove other message like WM_CREATE or WM_DESTROY because they don't relate to the problem. The `consoleOutput()` function is used for debugging and they works just fine.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (message){
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE: {
            try {
                if (OpenClipboard(hWnd)){
                    UINT uFormat = EnumClipboardFormats(0);         // Get the first clipboard format available
                    HANDLE hContent;
                    while (uFormat) { //Iterate through all formats
                        hContent = GetClipboardData(uFormat);   // Get the clipboard data of that format
                            if (hContent) {
                                SIZE_T size = GlobalSize(hContent); // Get the size of the data I just got
                                //ERROR
                            }
                        uFormat = EnumClipboardFormats(uFormat);    // Get the next format
                    }
                }
                CloseClipboard();
            }
            catch (int error) {
                CloseClipboard();           // Attempt to close clipboard if thing went wrong
                consoleOutput(GetLastError());
                throw;
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine with everything I tried to copy from text to some random files/directories. But my program gave me an error when I tried to copy a image, for example:

- Open an image using MS Paint, select any portion of the image and copy it and the error appears.
- Open an image using Picasa, right click and select copy and the error appears.
- Press PrntScr button and the error appears.

The error is throwed at `SIZE_T size = GlobalSize(hContent);` line, and it is either:

> Critical error detected c0000374 YClipboard.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

or

> Exception thrown at 0x77E17ECC (ntdll.dll) in YClipboard.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDD46116F.

The error is not persistent, most of the time it appeared right in the first copy, sometime I can copy the image, but do it multiple times with that same image cause the error. Above all, only attempt to copy "image" data cause the problem.

**What I have tried so far**

I am a novice about developing desktop app, and I my searching don't find the problem anywhere else. When I peek at the clipboard data using a third-party app, I found out the error only appear when my program met the `CF_BITMAP` or `CF_METAFILEPICT` format, and (not so) coincidentally both of those formats have a memory of size 0. Still I am unable to fix my problem.

**What I need**

Someone please enlighten me about this problem: what is the problem, the cause of it, how to fix it or just a suggestion about another method that help me read the size of clipboard data to replace `GlobalSize()` function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code, with a debugger, while inspecting the values of the local variables? Visual studio has a powerful debugger. The most common reason for an "access violation" is reading/writing to inaccessible memory (e.g. outside the bounds of array).

Comment: *I remove other message like WM_CREATE or WM_DESTROY because they don't relate to the problem.* -- You could remove everything and create a simple console Windows app with a `main` that just calls those Windows API functions.  Yes, you don't need a GUI app to do this.  Also, your `try` block doesn't throw anything.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you I am trying it right now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So even that may do too lol, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all clipboard formats present an `HGLOBAL` that you can use with functions like `GlobalSize()`.

For example, `CF_BITMAP` presents a handle to a bitmap; an `HBITMAP` that you can use with functions like `GetObject()`.

You'll need to handle those formats specially. See the [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx) list on MSDN for more information.

Comment: So there are no "generic solution" except handle each of them specifically? I am always afraid that I will miss something and caught an unexpected error afterward but if thing come to this I guess I have no choice. Thank you and upvoted.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your anser helps me fixing a long time bug of my project.